# Extract string between 2 strings and fetch to the end if 2nd string not found

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

What is the pattern to extract string between 2 strings and fetch to the end if 2nd string not found? For example: to retrieve value assigned to foo (value contains white spaces)

```
import re

s1 = 'quz=1, 2, 3 and foo=4, 5, 6 and bar=7, 8, 9'
m = re.match(pattern=r'^.*foo=(.*)\sand', string=s1)

assert m.group(1) == '4, 5, 6'

s2 = 'quz=1, 2, 3 and foo=4, 5, 6'
m = re.match(pattern=r'^.*foo=(.*)', string=s2)

assert m.group(1) == '4, 5, 6'
```

Thanks

Comment: `r'^.*foo=(.+?)(?:\sand|$)'` would work by making `and` optional match

Comment: You may also  use `r'foo=((?:(?! and).)*)'` but it is not that efficient. Another option is [`r'foo=(\S*(?:\s(?!and)\S*)*)'`](https://regex101.com/r/Xv590k/1).

Comment: thanks anubhava, it worked a treat. btw why did you changed foo=(.*) to foo=(.+?) ? Ta

Comment: @CanLu: It is because `.*` is greedy and would try to match longest string till end of string. So `r'^.*foo=(.*?)(?:\sand|$)'` would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *look ahead (?=...)* with an *or* logic (next `and` or end of string `$`):

Since you are not matching from the beginning of the string, it might be more convenient to use `re.search`; The non-greedy `.*?` regex is better suited if you only want to match to the next `and`;

```
import re
re.search(r'foo=(.*?)(?= and|$)', s1).group(1)
# '4, 5, 6'
re.search(r'foo=(.*?)(?= and|$)', s2).group(1)
# '4, 5, 6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex need to allow an `and` or **end of string** with a **lazy** quantifier. In your regex `.*` is **greedy** and would attempt to match longest string till end of string.

Following regex should work for you:

```
r'^.*foo=(.*?)(?:\sand|$)'
```

Here is full code:

```
>>> s1 = 'quz=1, 2, 3 and foo=4, 5, 6 and bar=7, 8, 9'
>>> s2 = 'quz=1, 2, 3 and foo=4, 5, 6'
>>> p = r'^.*foo=(.*?)(?:\sand|$)'

>>> print re.findall(p, s1)
['4, 5, 6']

>>> print re.findall(p, s2)
['4, 5, 6']
```